# How to set predefined page size as the default page size

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I want to set `A5` as my printer default paper size.

I tried following code But it won't work for me.

```
var paperSize = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.PaperName == "A5");
printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

Comment: That is going to be difficult if even possible. Most of the time the defaults are saved in the printer settings and are not directly editable by a programs instructions.

Comment: Is there a way to print my document in standard A5 sheet?

Comment: That depends if your printer properties allows you to select A5 as a paper size.

Comment: Changed above code "printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;" into  "printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;" and it Works!